# Procedure to mail 1040NR-EZ, 540NR from outside of US

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, california, state-taxes

I have to mail my federal and state tax returns 1040NR-EZ and 540NR to IRS and FTB, CA respectively from India? What are the mailing addresses and which is the best courier service to choose to ensure timely filing ?

Comment: Best courier service is product recommendation and out of scope here. The other question can be answered.